# Excel Ambiguity Plot

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently working through some data that has 4 properties. 2 Min and Max values for each. I want to know if it is possible to automate a plot as shown in the picture.

I am comparing data to see if the Min and Max for each value overlap on the X and Y axis.

I can do it by hand, but with the amount of data that will be used doing it by hand will be very time consuming.

If anyone knows if this is even possible or can direct me to any help on a solution I would be eternally greatful.

Steve

[image: Ambiguity Plot]

Thank you so much for your reply. That is very close to what I was hoping for. To give a little context to the situation. Imagine a 2D shape has an X length that is the range of a min and max. And the Y length is also from min to max.

For an example

Area 1 is

MinX = 10
MaxX = 20

So the length of X is 10

MinY = 30
MaxY = 50

Therefore the length of Y is 20

this would equate to a box that is 10 by 20

Area 2 is

MinX = 15
MaxX = 25

So the length of X is 10

MinY = 35
MaxY = 55

Therefore the length of Y is 20

this would equate to a box that is 10 by 20

We now have 2 areas that overlap in an area defined as 15 to 20 and 35 to 50

I would like to display this visually for multiple entries.

This can be seen in the image below (Colour is not essential and just to show you guys the different areas)

[Better Image of what the outcome should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEeQK.png)

Comment: Yes, it is possible with VBA. Unfortunately, exactly how is too broad of a question. Start coding. Ask another question if and when you get stuck at a specific point.

Comment: Thank you John, Would you have any clue what this type of plot/graph is called so i can broaden my search. At the moment I am at a blank.

Comment: Yo can add a shape in your sheet with `Worksheets("MySheet").Shapes.AddShape msoShapeRectangle, 10, 10, 20, 20`. You would have reorder your coordinate data, and then loop through them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited** The following is not a plot, but may help to visualize what you want. Data is in sheet `MyData`, and structured like in Nathan_sav's answer (starting in row 2; see image). "Plot" is draw in sheet `MyPlot`. Y values increases to the bottom of the page. For a nicer look, hide gridlines in worksheet `MyPlot`

Data structuring (sheet `MyData`):
[image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim dataWS As Worksheet
    Dim drawingWS As Worksheet
    Dim MyObject As Object, MyObject2 As Object
    Dim lLastRow As Long
    Dim lStartVisualizationX As Long, lStartVisualizationY As Long
    Dim lHigherXValue As Long, lHigherYValue As Long



    Set dataWS = Worksheets("MyData")
    Set drawingWS = Worksheets("MyPlot")

    lLastRow = dataWS.Cells(2, 2).End(xlDown).Row
    drawingWS.Columns("A:Z").EntireColumn.Delete

    lStartVisualizationX = 30 'X position where "graph" starts
    lStartVisualizationY = 30 'Y position where "graph" starts

    lHigherXValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(dataWS.Columns(4)) 'Maximun value of X
    lHigherYValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(dataWS.Columns(5)) 'Maximun value of Y
    lStepX = 10 'X divisions
    lStepY = 10 'Y divisions

    'Draw the "X axis and divisions and labels"
    For i = 0 To lHigherXValue Step lStepX
        'MyObject: lines
        Set MyObject = drawingWS.Shapes.AddLine(lStartVisualizationX + i, lStartVisualizationY, lStartVisualizationX + i, lStartVisualizationY + lHigherYValue)
        'MyObject2: labels
        Set MyObject2 = drawingWS.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationUpward, lStartVisualizationX + i - 2, lStartVisualizationY - 20, 10, 20)
        MyObject2.TextFrame.Characters.Text = i
        MyObject2.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Size = 6
        MyObject2.Line.Visible = msoFalse
        MyObject2.TextFrame.HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        MyObject2.TextFrame.VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        If i <> 0 Then
            MyObject.Line.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 22
            MyObject.Line.DashStyle = msoLineRoundDot
        End If
    Next

    'Draw the "Y axis and divisions"
    For i = 0 To lHigherYValue Step lStepY
        Set MyObject = drawingWS.Shapes.AddLine(lStartVisualizationX, lStartVisualizationY + i, lStartVisualizationX + lHigherXValue, lStartVisualizationY + i)
        Set MyObject2 = drawingWS.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, lStartVisualizationX - 20, lStartVisualizationY + i - 2, 20, 10)
        MyObject2.TextFrame.Characters.Text = i
        MyObject2.TextFrame.Characters.Font.Size = 6
        MyObject2.Line.Visible = msoFalse
        MyObject2.TextFrame.HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        MyObject2.TextFrame.VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        If i <> 0 Then
            MyObject.Line.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 22
            MyObject.Line.DashStyle = msoLineRoundDot
        End If
    Next

    For i = 2 To lLastRow
        'data is MinX, MinY, MaxX, MaxY
        Set MyObject = drawingWS.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, lStartVisualizationX + dataWS.Cells(i, 2), lStartVisualizationY + dataWS.Cells(i, 3), (dataWS.Cells(i, 4) - dataWS.Cells(i, 2)), (dataWS.Cells(i, 5) - dataWS.Cells(i, 3)))
        With MyObject
            .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
            .Fill.Solid
            .Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = Cells(i, 2).Interior.ColorIndex
            .Fill.Transparency = 0.7
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Result (sheet `MyPlot`):

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure this really answers it. You've added three shapes to a sheet?

Comment: Yes, its adding three shapes to a sheet. It works for me. With several caveats: there are no axes, and the values of each shape are rendered as the position of the shapes, so shapes with higher values are displayed to the right (X, ok) and to the bottom (Y, not intuitive). But with a shape you can further define color (for example getting the color of the data cells) and transparency (cool...).

Comment: so you've added three shapes to a sheet, with the incorrect placement, and the incorrect output?

Comment: @Tom Yes. But if the aim is just to know if there are any overlaps (as OP wants), this approach can show that clearly. And placement is not completely incorrect. I like the visualization really.

Comment: @CMArg That is very close to what I was looking for and I have tried to give a bit more context above. Thank you again

Comment: @CMArg sorry for the delay, I have been enjoying a long weekend with the family. That worked brilliantly thank you. I had to make a little change in the drawing of the X axis as you had referenced the Y to set it up and not the X but i am more than happy to let that slip with the result of the rest. Thank you so much

Comment: @CMArg when i have finished making your great start suit my specific needs I will post up the code for others

Answer (score 2):

It can be done using formula and conditional formatting also, I've done an example using 2 elements based on your example and the formula being

```
=IF(AND(H$17>=$B$5,H$17<=$C$5,$G16>=$D$5,$G16<=$E$5),2,IF(AND(H$17>=$B$4,H$17<=$C$4,$G16>=$D$4,$G16<=$E$4),1,0))
```

Here is an image.

[image]

Hope this helps, just a suggestion.

Comment: This is an interesting approach. And can be coded to VBA.